# InstallShield: Replace one file in installation with another provided by interactive user

Tags: windows, installation, installshield

I have a new InstallShield (Pro) project that I'm using to install a Windows .Net application.  Among the files installed is a text .config file.  I would like to offer the interactive setup user the ability to override that file with a custom file (selected by the user).

I have created a custom dialog for the user to provide the file path.  The file path modifies a custom public property (called `CUSTOMBOOTSTRAP`).

Now for the tricky bit:  how do I override my default file with whatever the user provides at this path?  Is this a custom action I need, or is there some other way to do this (dynamic file linking?).

Thanks,
-James

Answer (score 1):

I find this question interesting, mostly because MSI is rather poorly suited for this. So here are some considerations for designing your approach to this:

**What happens in repair?**
Are the files in questions versioned, and if so could the user supply a lower version than the one you include? (Or similarly could the rest of [file versioning rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599.aspx) result in a similar situation?) If so, you will want to avoid having your .msi "own" the file, because it will overwrite the user-chosen file with the one it knows about. Further, unless there's a reason to believe the user-provided path will remain usable, you would have to handle when it goes missing before a repair occurs.

**What happens at uninstallation?** Should the file be removed or left behind? Will you know its name? (Consider the "remember property" pattern if the name can vary but you need to remove the file.)

**What options do you have?**
"Semi-custom actions" might be able to address this use case in a couple different ways. You could create temporary entries for either the [`DuplicateFile` table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368335.aspx) or the [`MoveFile` table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370055.aspx). Or if you're willing to do enough contortions to fill out the `Directory` table and `Media` table, you could even populate the [`File` table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596.aspx). I expect these would all be hard to manage correctly. (Again, don't forget repair and remove - the latter may require temporary [`RemoveFile` table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371201.aspx) entries.) Or you can go full-blown custom action that copies or moves the file directly. Or you might be able to rearchitect the application:

**Does it make sense for this to be a user file?** Perhaps the file is a form of configuration that needs to be shared across the whole machine, or even configured by the network administrator. If so, you're probably best off with one of the above approaches so it is installed by an administrator and then protected by standard Windows filesystem security. But if it's really a user configuration file, perhaps it should be managed in your application or directly by the user.

Comment: Michael, doesn't the IS SAB installer do this with the License XML file?

Comment: I'll have to look into that. It may instead set an environment variable to point to it (assuming you mean the license.lic file) which dodges most of the mess, although this approach would require the original file stick around.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it pops a file browse dialog during the install and then copies it to the dest dir.  I've never looked at it in ORCA to see how it works exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up discussing the situation with InstallShield (made by FlexEra) and they recommended the following:

1. Don't put the original file in the [InstallDir] if possible.
2. Create separate Components for each of the variants of the file, each with a different release flag.
3. Only install the Components associated with the release flag you want.

This partially addresses my question but not entirely, because it doesn't let me specify a new file at install-time; I can merely select among existing files.